# use htaccess to hide a login page

Tags: php, .htaccess

1.How to use ht access file  to hide some entry page ,that is we enter to the child  site by typing the URL in the URL bar of browser ,instead of clicking links of my parent site .

2.Is there any way to get the previous URL used in a a browser in PHP

Please give me some suggestions

I tried this

```
    if(($req->getrequestPath() == 'test') && ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == '') ){
                header('HTTP/ 401 Unauthorized');           
    }
```

Also I added ErrorDocument 401 /unauthorize.php in .htaccess file,
 but then it doesnt seem to work.

PS:Am doing this is concrete5

I tried to give

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!='blahblah' || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!='blahblah'){ 
        header('WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="Check my Site"');
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
}
```

`header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");` is supposed to take me to .htaccess file right?Even that's not happening !!
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** to know your reference url.
 try `print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`, but don't forget to escape it with `addslashes` or the like since it is a common attack vector.

```
if(addslashes($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) != "your address here")
{
   die("not allowed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition,  you can check %{HTTP_REFERER} in RewriteCond in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/ [nc]
RewriteRule loginpage.php - [R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect client url to parent site by using below ReWrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

The above example redirect all url to index page only. Similarly you can redirect client url to where you need to redirect..!